# Java Xattjr on Mac - Can't load resource: libxattrj.dylib

Tags: java, macos, file, attributes

In my quest to write file x-attributes on mac, I came across [an old library](https://github.com/IsNull/xattrj). It seems that Java does not support X-attr on Mac, this is a known issue (since 2014), and the cited response was to use the third party library ([Link to the bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040830)). I have not seen any other libraries capable of doing this, and this one has not been updated in years. In my case, when trying to use it, I get this error:

```
Java.io.Exception : Classloader - Can't load Resource: libxattrj.dylib
```

If anyone can get this running, I'd love to know how. For reference, it is not in the maven public repo. Add this to pom.xml to import it the library.

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo1</id>
        <name>liferay</name>
        <url>https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</dependencies>
....
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
        <artifactId>ch.securityvision.xattrj</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```